# Qtservice installation on ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-14.04, qt5.5

i downloaded qtsolution from git and i want to install (run) qtservice on my linux machine hosted on virtualbox.

Can anyone give me specific instructions how to do it. Qt is already installed, all libs, compiler and other necessary things. I have already successfully compiled some parts of my app (build in visual studio and later compiled on ubuntu) and in this point i need qtservice, but compiling is quite different from visual studio compiling.

Ubuntu version 14.04
Qt 5.5

Comment: Did you read the [INSTALL.txt](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/blob/master/qtservice/INSTALL.TXT)?

Answer (score 0):

i am not quite sure about your exact question but if you are asking about how to connect qt-solution lib to your current project it is not that difficult. You have to add the path to the directory containing qtsolutions lib to file *.pro  ( i did add the following line "include(../../../../qt-solutions/qtservice/src/qtservice.pri )" at the bottom of the file *.pro of my project ) I needed just qtservice ( but you can use others in the same of course ) As you see it is just a relative path ( from my working directory ). appropriate "commnon.pri" file will be add to your project.